# Installing PECL extension error

Tags: php, apc, pecl

I downloaded a PECL extension and executed:

```
$ phpize
$ ./configure
```

The following command generated dozens of errors:

```
$ make
```

I suspect that the first two errors lead to the others:

/Users/afilina/Downloads/APC-3.1.9/apc.h:61:17: error: php.h: No such file or directory
/Users/afilina/Downloads/APC-3.1.9/apc.h:62:30: error: main/php_streams.h: No such file or directory

Here is an example of the dozens of syntax errors:

/Users/afilina/Downloads/APC-3.1.9/apc.h:69: error: syntax error before 'TSRMLS_DC'

Does anyone have pointers as to what might have happened? Installing using the "pecl" command is not an option as my PEAR installation is corrupted.

Comment: You likely need the `php5-devel` or `php-devel` package.

Answer (score 3):

You need the PHP headers. Depending the Distro, or OS these may be found in a different manner.

In debian you need install "php5-dev":

```
apt-get install php5-dev
```

Realy i don't know how install it in Mac.